# ASP.NET c# Profile: GetProfile not avalaible

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, profile, asp.net-profiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use Profile.GetProfile() in a library class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446826/how-to-use-profile-getprofile-in-a-library-class)

How to get profile in a cs class? It works fine in aspx.cs class.

```
 ProfileCommon profile= HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetProfile(username);
```

How to make GetProfile() available in cs class? please advice, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answer about profiling users. There is all you need:

[User profiles in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654817/profiling-in-asp-net/12655009#12655009)

Comment: in your code, you are creating a profile, how would I retrieve an existing profile? thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer again. First you need to register profile provider and profile properties inside web.config. Create function creates profile or retrieves it if already exists.

Comment: In your case you are probably missing configuration or sqlProfile tables (if you are using SqlProfileProvider).

Comment: You are right. Thanks alot. Once I changed defaultProvider to SqlProvider It worked. Couple you please explain me the difference between AspNetSqlProfileProvider and SqlProvider, why it didnt work with AspNetSqlProfileProvider ? also in aspx.cs file I would use GetProfile() but in class file I use .ProfileBase.Create(), is it the same thing? Should I be using .ProfileBase.Create() in the aspx.cs file as well? thanks alot.

Comment: I dont think provider of type AspNetSqlProfileProvider exists. This is just a default name used for SqlProfileProvider. I guess you have mistyped yourself while altering web.config. When you want to access specific profile just use ProfileBase.Create("SomeUserName") and you will be on the safe side. Just ProfileBase.Create() will not give you a result you are looking for.